# Memory pressure warning, while take screen shot.

Tags: ios

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(screenRect.size);
```

If I use this, no memory pressure occurs. but If I use below line memory pressure occurs.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(screenRect.size, NO, 4.0f);
```

I don't know why this hapening.. Any body tell me how to handle this?

Comment: The last parameter is the image scale. Why do you wish to create an image using a scale of 4.0?

Comment: @rmaddy:If I give 0, that also cause this same issue.

Comment: 0 means to use the current scale - either 1 or 2 depending on the device. The 1st method always uses a scale of 1.

Comment: @rmaddy:I can't understand can  you please tell briefly. Then I need to use this in IOS6 and IOS7.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "memory pressure", I assume what you mean is a memory warning/crash. The reason for that is with the first example:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(screenRect.size);
```

You're creating a context of the current screen size where as when you use:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(screenRect.size, NO, 4.0f);
```

You're creating a context 4 times the size of the current screen size which requires more memory, and if the device doesn't have enough memory to allocate then bad things will happen.

You can watch the memory allocations by using Instruments. Product -> Profile (⌘I) and selecting 'Allocations' from the Templates:

[image: Instruments - Allocations]